# D3 single line chart with tsv data

Tags: d3.js, linechart

I am trying to import single-column tsv data in order to create a line chart with d3.js, but I am getting an error message, and I don't know how to solve this.

Here is my code (based on already existing examples):

```
<script>
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50}, // as if margin would be an object
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis() // we create a new axis
    .scale(x) // we set the scale based on the var x
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d,i) {
      console.log('Plotting X value for data point: ' + d + ' using index: ' + i + ' to be at: ' + x(i) + ' using our xScale.');
      return x(i); 
    })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.values); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");



d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.length; })); // get min and max date values
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.values; }));

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis); // we call also a var!!

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Values");

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line);
});

function type(d) {
  d.values = +d.values; // converts string to number
  return d;
}
</script>
```

And here is the tsv file:

```
values
1.5
2.6
3.4
7.8
3.8
1.0
6.7
```

The error I get is:

> "Invalid value for <path> attribute d="MNaN,416.9117647058824LNaN,344.1176470588235LNaN,291.17647058823525LNaN,0LNaN,264.70588235294116LNaN,450LNaN,72.79411764705881"

Apparently my data index is not correctly read.

Could someone maybe help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One change instead of

```
  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.length; })); // get min and max
```

Do this since the x axis is the length of the array.

```
  x.domain([0, data.length-1]); // get min and max
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/H7mRTv5bHkM7vPAGxQcR?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, Cyril! This helped a lot!

Comment: cool! you can accept it as answer ...this is how you can accept it http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work